# How to give file input from a dir and produce the output in a different dir using GNU parallel?

Tags: bash, bioinformatics, gnu-parallel

I am trying to use `parallel` for bam to sort and index using `samtools` and producing the output in a given `output_dir` but facing some problems.

I tried so far the following, which is working but I don't want that dir name "1" within `output_dir` and also getting results files within `input_dir`.

```
parallel --results output_dir 'samtools sort -o {.}.sorted.bam {}' ::: input_dir/*.bam
```

This, from comments, is not working:

```
parallel 'samtools sort -o output_dir/{.}.sorted.bam {}' ::: input_dir/*.bam
```

I get the error

```
“[E::hts_open_format] Failed to open file output_dir/input_dir/A-8_20181222_0036.sorted.bam”
```

Note: This is just one tool (`samtools`) I am asking but I will be using other tools that produce output using `--output` / `-o` flag.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. What behavior do you see at the moment and what would you like for it to be? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Aren't you simply looking for `parallel 'samtools sort -o output_dir/{.}.sorted.bam {}' ::: input_dir/*.bam`?

Comment: Thats not working, getting error: ERROR: “[E::hts_open_format] Failed to open file output_dir/input_dir/A-8_20181222_0036.sorted.bam”

Comment: But that's what you are trying to achieve? Maybe [edit] your question.

Comment: I guess try with `{/.}` instead of `{.}`

Comment: The problem is, than when you use `-o` then `samtools` decides where to put the output. GNU Parallel does not. @tripleee's solution is most likely what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is "how can I add a different directory instead of the input directory", just put it verbatim before the `{/.}` token.  (You had `{.}` but we also want to trim the directory name.)

```sh
parallel 'samtools sort -o output_dir/{/.}.sorted.bam {}' ::: input_dir/*.bam
```

See [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#Reference) for more ideas, there is a large number of transformations you can perform on the input token.